# opengles java nio buffers

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, nio

My game has two screens. Each screen is rendered with a class named SpriteBatcher. The first screen renders fine. The second fails and throws me the above error.

```
 11-30 13:10:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad position (limit 0): 2
 11-30 13:10:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): at java.nio.Buffer.positionImpl(Buffer.java:357)
 11-30 13:10:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1621): at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:351)
 11-30 13:10:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1621):
 atcom.rim.framework.gl.Vertices.bind(Vertices.java:66)
```

So i am trying to access buffer's position 2 while the buffer is 0 sized. In my code though i dont see any bug.

```
    this.vertexSize = (2 + (hasColor?4:0) + (hasTexCoords?2:0)) * 4;

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(maxVertices * vertexSize); ///8 bit = 1 byte, 4 byte = 32bit float
    buffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertices = buffer.asFloatBuffer();
```

The problem as the error states is in my bind() method:

```
    public void bind() {
    GL10 gl = glGraphics.getGL();

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    vertices.position(0);
    gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, vertexSize, vertices);

    if(hasColor) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        vertices.position(2);
        gl.glColorPointer(4, GL10.GL_FLOAT, vertexSize, vertices);
    }

    if(hasTexCoords) {
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        vertices.position(hasColor?6:2);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, vertexSize, vertices);
    }
}
```

The bug was caused by the spritebatcher.bind method. I was passing zero sprites so i ended up rendering nulls...

Comment: What is the value of `maxVertices` when you allocate the buffer?

Comment: maxSprite * 4 (maxSprite = 1000)

Answer (score 0):

[NIO ByteBuffers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) have a *limit* and a *capacity*.  The limit is a "soft" limit; the capacity defines how much the buffer can actually hold.  You're trying to position past the soft limit.

On a newly-created buffer, the limit will be equal to the capacity.  It sounds like something changed the limit to zero.  You can reset the limit (and mark, and position) with the `clear()` method.

Comment: I was checking my code for the last 30 minutes. My limits seem to be fine. I will use log.d to check the buffer limit now...